# getting an error when updating a view through a job in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a view that has to be updated every hour. For that I created a job with this query on the command

```
Update GP_Batch_View
```

but once I run that job, it gave me an error. See pictures below.[image]

[image]

Job actions
[image]

Even though it is giving me that error, is updating the view, but I would like to get rig of it. Do you guys know what is the issue here?

Comment: Try to run t-sql code from your step 1 as a query in the Management studio and see what happens

Comment: Try expanding the history row and looking at the row for step 1; that should have a better error message.

Comment: when I expand the history it gives me the message that is on the second picture

Comment: What is the On Success action of job step 1?  In the past I've had mine accidentally set to "Abort job with error" so it shows an error even when it is successful.

Comment: When you say "updating a view", what is it, exactly, that is being updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short version: I think you might be confused about how views work. I suspect **you don't need this SQL Agent job at all**.

Now, for the detailed explanation:

`UPDATE` is a specific kind of SQL query that is used to change the data of a database table. Example:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column3 = 'Some value'
WHERE Table1ID = 5;
```

As such, the query `UPDATE GP_Batch_View` is invalid SQL because it's not updating anything.

Now, if what you're hoping to do is have the view refresh itself so that the data it can return is up-to-date, I have good news for you: **views already do that** automatically.

Views are just `SELECT` statements. Say we have a Person table that has several columns, but we only care about first name and last name. We can create a view that is defined as so:

```
CREATE VIEW SomeView
AS 
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName
FROM Person p;
```

This kind of view can have `UPDATE` queries run against it because it only includes one table. So, if Jane Doe decides to change her last name to Smith, we can run the following:

```
UPDATE SomeView
SET LastName = 'Smith'
WHERE FirstName = 'Jane' AND LastName = 'Doe'
```

This will actually update the data in the **Person table** and change Jane Doe's last name to Smith. The view will then automatically reflect the changes because, well, it's just a `SELECT` statement in reality.

If you adjust the view to include some other table, like....

```
CREATE VIEW SomeView
AS 
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, a.Address1, a.City, a.State
FROM Person p INNER JOIN Address a ON p.PersonID = a.PersonID;
```

then you'll no longer be able to run `UPDATE` statements against this view. However, if Jane Smith decides to change her last name back to Doe, you can just run your `UPDATE` against the Person table...

```
UPDATE Person
SET LastName = 'Doe'
WHERE FirstName = 'Jane' AND LastName = 'Smith'
```

...and the view will automatically pick up the change because, again, it's just a simple `SELECT` statement under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you manually run the"Update_GP_Batch_View" SP or just copy the Sp code and running it in SQL query analyzer. It will give you exact error message if fails.

Comment: This should probably be a comment since its not technically a complete solution.

Comment: depends on how long the code is if you use a tick key (the one right before the #1) before and after it shows it `as code`

Comment: or you could temporally add code in the SP. like Try..catch or raise error.

Comment: You Update a view GP_Batch_View ... can you paste the rest of code here?

Comment: I was searching on google and found that not all views can be updated. The first requirement to a view can be updated, it has to be defined based on one and only one table. Mine has 2 http://www.w3resource.com/sql/update-views/sql-update-views.php#exam6

Comment: @cojimarmiami: I think there's some confusion here. Do you want the data of the view to update itself or are you trying to modify some specific data in the view from one value to another value?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you need to look at the proc in terms of adding better error trapping to it. The error is general because you aren't returning any specifics.